# How to calculate expected value of a Palindrome-Finding game

Tags: r, math, statistics, probability

[Given question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu2uP.png)
So I have this question. I have written a game in R in which there is an 8x8 matrix of letters from to z. You start on any random square, then randomly move to another square and decide if you want to collect the letter on that square. In this way, you collect 5 letters that form a palindrome.

Now, in the above image, the number of turns when starting on a square A is given in a list. How do I calculate the expected value of this square? I have written some code in which, I count the occurrences of values in 10s, 20s, 30s and 40s and multiplying them by 10, 20, 30 and 40 and then summing up to get the expected value. Not sure if this is correct.

```
# For square A
vals <- c(10, 20, 30, 40)
probs <- c(0.545, 0.363, 0.090, 0)
expected_val_sq_A <- sum(vals*probs)
print(expected_val_sq_A)


# For square B
vals <- c(10, 20, 30, 40)
probs <- c(0.181, 0.363, 0.181, 0.272)
expected_val_sq_b <- sum(vals*probs)
print(expected_val_sq_b)
```

Comment: This is a programming venue. We don't see any code.

Comment: Your method is not correct since you have arbitrarily chosen bins of 10-19, 20-29, etc. You could do a t-test on the actual values, to which the result is that starting on square B is likely to take more "turns" than that for square A (p=0.03).